# How to show 1 element from object Date?

Tags: javascript

So guys I have 2 questions:

**1)** Why this function shows at the beginning except dates `undefined`?

**2)** How to show not all dates, but only 1/2/3 etc. of them?

```js
const today = new Date();

const getCurrentDate = (d) => {
  
  let setWeek;
    
    for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
     let x = new Date(d);
     x.setDate(x.getDate() + i);
      let fullDate = x.toLocaleString('en-gb', { day:'numeric' , weekday: 'long', month: 'long' });
      
      setWeek += fullDate
    }

  return setWeek
}

console.log(getCurrentDate(today))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter with an array for range of date offsets to use.
setWeek needs to be initalized to a value.

```js
const today = new Date();

const getCurrentDate = (d, dates=[1,2,3,4,5,6]) => {
    let setWeek='';
    const x = new Date(d);
    return dates.map(i => {
      x.setDate(x.getDate() + i);
      const fullDate = x.toLocaleString('en-gb', 
        { day:'numeric' , weekday: 'long', month: 'long' });
      return fullDate;
    }).join(' ');
}

console.log(getCurrentDate(today))
console.log(getCurrentDate(today, [1,2,3]))
console.log(getCurrentDate(today, [1,3,6]))
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Why this function shows at the beginning except dates undefined?

Because `setWeek` starts out with the value `undefined`, and you're doing `setWeek += fullDate`, which is `setWeek = setWeek + fullDate`, so `undefined` is converted to `"undefined"` and then `fullDate` is added to it. Initialize `setWeek` with `""` to avoid it.

> 2) How to show not all dates, but only 1/2/3 etc. of them?

That depends which dates you want, but basically you would do one of two things:

1. Use `i += 2` if you want to do every other date (and change `+ 1` to `+ 2` when you're updating the date), or
2. Use an `if` within the `for` to decide whether to add the current date to `setWeek`.